# Issue with Delete button in GridView in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, gridview

This is my code:

```
private void Bind()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Dido\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CourseProjectCars\CourseProjectCars\DataCars.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from SuperCars", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }





private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Dido\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CourseProjectCars\CourseProjectCars\DataCars.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    SqlCommand delcmd = new SqlCommand();
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1 && dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index != dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        delcmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM SuperCars WHERE Car='%" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "%'";
        con.Open();
        delcmd.Connection = con;
        delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
        MessageBox.Show("Row Deleted");
    }
    Bind();
}
```

I want to put a delete button in my application. When I select a row and click the delete button, it throws the exception below:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please display the code in side Bind() function. I think record was not removed in the database and when you call Bind() function at that time record again bind in the gridview.
I think your delete query is wrong , if you want to remove record which have car as cell[0] value so query will be as below :

```
delcmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM SuperCars WHERE Car Like '%" +dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "%'";
```

Comment: I pasted it in above. Please, take a look.

Comment: Yes, I think when you click on delete at that time GridView row not selected that is chance to get the error.

Comment: Thanks that helps even more!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't know how to select a row as well as how the `DataGridView` understands when a row is called ***selected***. To select a row, you have to click on the row header, or if you want to select the row just by clicking on any cell on the row, just set the property `SelectionMode` to `DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`. Then the `SelectedRows` should have at least 1 item, the index out of range exception should not be thrown any more.

If you intend to allow user to delete 1 row at a time, I think you can use the property `CurrentRow` to get the current selected row, you can also use the `CurrentCell` or `CurrentCellAddress` and derive the selected row from them.

Comment: This solves the problem with the exception but it still dosn't delete the entry from the database...